# User.ReadWrite Permissions in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I'm developing an application that incorporates the Skype for Business Online Web SDK. I've noticed that it is not possible to access information about the signed in user's Skype account/profile (via Skype's mePerson object).

The only way that I see to do this now is by having yourself as a contact and accessing information about that account/profile, via the Skype person object. This doesn't seem possible to me as it isn't feasible to set a requirement upon every client using my application to have themselves added as a contact on Skype for Business.

This issue is related to the one posted here, on the GitHub Skype Web SDK Samples page: https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-web-sdk-samples/issues/1

My question: Are there plans to add the User.ReadWrite Permissions in Azure AD for an application extending Skype for Business? Or, is there a known workaround to retrieve the signed in user's profile/account information, which includes status, activity, or avatar/avatarUrl?

I've also posted this on the Microsoft Azure forums:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/27d6ebdc-f023-4829-96dd-eefb9e1aaeaf/userreadwrite-permissions-in-azure-ad?forum=SkypeWebSDK

However, I've had no response so I'm also posting here in hopes of anybody having any input. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you might have noticed from the issue link in GitHub, the permissions for the information you're trying to grab have been turned on in Azure AD.

[image: Azure AD SfB Online]

You can plug in your Azure AD settings into the Interactive Web SDK to see it in action: https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk

Before you sign in, you'll need to do the following in the Azure AD management console:

1. Update your app to use the permissions in the image
2. Change your app's reply URL to this: https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk
3. Make sure you turn on OAuth implicit flow by modifying your app's manifest.  Steps here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt622687%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 under "Configure your app for OAuth implicit grant flow"
4. Paste your app's Azure client ID into the "Client id" field on https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk

After you sign in, you'll notice one of the examples in the left hand navigation will let you view the signed-in user's presence, ID, etc.

I've also created a forked version of the Web SDK samples that you can easily update with your own Azure AD settings and deploy to your localhost.  You might find this more useful for playing around than the hosted Interactive Web SDK.

https://github.com/tamhinsf/skype-web-sdk-samples